# How can compile and run java programme in php?

Tags: java, php

this is my java file.

hello.java

```
class hello
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      System.out.println("Hello");
   }
}
```

i want to compile and run this file in php.
This is my php file.

index.php.

```
<?php
    exec('java'.Hello.java, $output);
    if ($resultCode)
    {
       echo "Result: " . $resultCode . "\n";
      //echo implode("\n", $output);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

create `jar file` from source and with php, run exec() command and run this command:

```
java -jar MyJar.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<?
exec('java -Xmx1024m -jar "/home/blahblahblah/mydomain/testjava/Test.jar"');
?>
```

Refer this:
 http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/doc/how_it_works.php

More examples you can refer from this:

http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/FAQ.html

Answer (score 0):

If it is single file compiled Java code (.class), then just run using:

```
<?php
exec("/path/to/java/bin/java /path/to/your/class/file/hello");
?>
```

**Note**:
The uncompiled java program (.java) can not be run until it is compiled to runnable file (.class)